# Access Podman REST API from TestContainer

Tags: linux, java-8, maven-3, podman

I develop a Java application using Maven 3 and Podman 1.8.0. I understand that Podman provide a Docker compatible REST API.

Java integration test use TestContainer framework. TestContainer is not able to connect to Podman REST API. I have the same problem with the python application use to test Podman. Is it a problem with user account? Does Podman 1.8 release support REST API yet?

Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Podman 1.8 does not include Docker APIs, it was first [introduced in v2.0](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podmans-new-rest-api). To enable the API Podman needs to start as a service, as explained in the previous link, or in the [Podman documentation](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-system-service.1.html).

In my scripts I use something like this:

```
podman system service --time=0 & 
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/user/$(id -u)/podman/podman.sock
```

DOCKER_HOST is set in the environment for the clients, to modify the default Docker daemon socket. The value may vary depending on how the service starts (root/rootless) as explained in [Podman documentation](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-system-service.1.html).

I run in few issues using Podman v2 as a service and rootless mode, if you can I would suggest the [latest 3+](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases) at the time of writing.