# Using fabric8io docker-maven-plugin with podman, mvn docker:build causes IO-Exception

Tags: maven, podman, fabric8

I'd like to use the [docker-maven-plugin (0.33.0)](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin) with [podman (2.0.6)](https://podman.io). According to this [issue](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/issues/1330) this should be possible - at an experimental stage. Here is, what I did.

**Set an alias for docker**

```
alias docker=podman
```

**Start podman REST service**

```
podman system service -t 0 &
```

**Set DOCKER_HOST to the socket file**

```
unix:/run/user/7001/podman/podman.sock
```

**Try to build an image from a dockerfile**

```
mvn docker:build
```

And get:

```
[INFO] Building tar: /[...]/tmp/docker-build.tar
[INFO] DOCKER> [myapp:latest] "myapp": Created docker-build.tar in 918 milliseconds
Sep 02, 2020 2:39:24 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (jnr.enxio.channels.NativeException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://127.0.0.1:1: Connection reset by peer
Sep 02, 2020 2:39:24 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://127.0.0.1:1
Sep 02, 2020 2:39:25 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (jnr.enxio.channels.NativeException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://127.0.0.1:1: Connection reset by peer
Sep 02, 2020 2:39:25 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://127.0.0.1:1
Sep 02, 2020 2:39:25 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (jnr.enxio.channels.NativeException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://127.0.0.1:1: Connection reset by peer
Sep 02, 2020 2:39:25 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://127.0.0.1:1
[ERROR] DOCKER> Unable to build image [myapp] : Connection reset by peer [Connection reset by peer]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

It seems, that it is not a permission problem. I'm able to connect to the socket with curl and with the same user

```
curl -i --unix-socket /run/user/7001/podman/podman.sock http://localhost/info
... 200 OK ... and json payload
```

Any idea what possibly goes wrong in my setup?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476215/access-podman-rest-api-from-testcontainer

Answer (score 0):

Try setting DOCKER_HOST this way: `DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/7001/podman/podman.sock`